# How to Put condition in order by sql Query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table name :- xyztable and in this table i have 3 column

A:- id
B:- Name
c:- Order_number

i have a sample data like

```
Id Name order_nmber  
1  A    1  
2  K    0  
3  B    6  
4  c    3  
5  P    0  
6  d    5  
7  e    2  
8  O    0
```

I wrote the query is

```
select  * from xyztable order by order_number ASC;
```

that give me the result is

```
Id Name order_nmber 
2  K    0
5  P    0
8  O    0
1  A    1
7  e    2
4  c    3 
6  d    5
3  B    6
```

But i want the result like :-

```
Id Name order_nmber 
1  A    1
7  e    2
4  c    3 
6  d    5
3  B    6
2  K    0
5  P    0
8  O    0
```

So how can i get this in single query....Please help!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do like below:

```
select  * from xyztable order by order_number = 0, order_number ASC;
```

Comment: @DavidJohn `order_number = 0` will return `1` when `order_number` is `0`, otherwise return `0`, so order by it first will make the rows with  `order_number = 0` come to last.

Answer (score 4):

```
select  * from xyztable 
order by  case when order_number=0 then 1 else 0 end ASC, order_number ASC;
```

Comment: `case when order_number=0 then 1 else 0 end` is just the same as `order_number=0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM xyztable ORDER BY order_number = 0, order_number;
```